# Smarty Cache Issue

Tags: smarty

I have problem on including a template within another template.I want the smarty to load fresh tpl everytime i refresh instead of showing it from cache or templates_c.When i goggled and checked for a solution I had found below nocache but it doesnot seemed to work in my case.I do use smarty version 2.

{include file="`$theme`/`$content`" nocache}

Please show some light

Answer (score 0):

Using such code construction as you provided in your example is available in Smarty 3
(link to docs: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.include.tpl)

In Smarty 2 you cann't use `nocache` option, but you can try to use another options. For example `$smarty->caching = 1`.

Look at the documentation page for Smarty 2: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching.tpl

Comment: Thanks for the reference. How to include a tpl using in the {insert} function in smarty.for e.g. It shows error {insert file.tpl}http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.insert.tpl. Please let me know the good way